# cut interval array, resizing

Tags: arrays, matlab, resize

If I have a 1D array:

```
A = [10,21,23,25,32,37,42,48,55,58]
```

which has 10 values. I would like to create a new array:

```
B=[25,32,37,42]
```

keeping only 4 values, removing the first 3 and last 3 values.

In my script the `A` array has size 1 300 , and the `B` array has to be 1 200, +/-50 values off each side.

Please, what is the more efficient way to do that?

Comment: I knew that was so easy! :D but I spend 3 hours without find it. THANK YOU!!! (I was trying to write it with a looping, as I am writing a script in Matlab and FORTRAN also)

Comment: B = A(51:end-50) ... I think it must be like that

Comment: oh yeah thats right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B = A(51:end-50)`

`end` is a key word for array index